# Transpose every 4 rows into 4 individual columns

Tags: r, list, web-scraping, transpose, rvest

I am trying to scrape the date, title, and reviews from IMDB with the following loop:

```
   library(rvest)
   library(dplyr)
   library(stringr)
   library(tidyverse)

   ID <- 4633694

data <- lapply(paste0('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt', ID, '/reviews?filter=prolific', 1:20),
                   function(url){
                     url %>% read_html() %>% 
                       html_nodes(".review-date,.rating-other-user-rating,.title,.show-more__control") %>% 
                       html_text() %>%
                       gsub('[\r\n\t]', '', .)
                   })
```

Which provides 20 pages worth of review data in the following format repeating the same pattern:

```
   col1
1 10/10
2 If this was..
3 14 December 2018
4 I have to say, and no...
5
6
7 10/10
8 Stan Lee Is Smiling Right Now...
9 17 December 2018
10 A movie worthy of...
11
12
13 10/10
14 the most visually stunning film I've ever seen...
15 20 December 2018
16 There's hardly anything... 
17.
18.
```

I was wondering if there is a way to transpose every 4 rows into individual columns so that each attribute is aligned in the appropriate column, like this:

```
         Date          Rating     Title            Review
1. 14 December 2018    10/10    If this was..    I have to...
2. 17 December 2018    10/10   Stan Lee Is...    A movie worthy...
3. 20 December 2018    10/10  the most visually.. There's hardly anything...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text_data = gsub('\\b(\\d+/\\d+)\\b','\n\\1',paste(grep('\\w',x$col1,value = TRUE),collapse = ':')) 

read.csv(text=text_data,h=F,sep=":",strip.white = T,fill=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
     V1                                                V2               V3                         V4 V5
1 10/10                                     If this was.. 14 December 2018   I have to say, and no... NA
2 10/10                  Stan Lee Is Smiling Right Now... 17 December 2018       A movie worthy of... NA
3 10/10 the most visually stunning film I've ever seen... 20 December 2018 There's hardly anything... NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method.

Data:

```r
x <- read.csv2(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
col1
10/10
If this was..
14 December 2018
I have to say, and no...


10/10
Stan Lee Is Smiling Right Now...
17 December 2018
A movie worthy of...


10/10
the most visually stunning film I've ever seen...
20 December 2018
There's hardly anything... 
.
.")
```

To start, we "find" each of the top-rows, in this case it looks like a date. Note that you may want/need to fine-tune this regex minimize your false-positives and false-negatives.

```r
ind <- grep("^[0-9]+/[0-9]+", x$col1)
x$col1[ind]
# [1] "10/10" "10/10" "10/10"
```

The bottom line is place into `ind` the indices of the first-row for each block.

From here, let's extract each block up until where the next block starts (minus 1), up through the end of the frame's column:

```r
y <- Map(function(a,b) x$col[a:b], ind, c(ind[-1], nrow(x)))
str(y)
# List of 3
#  $ : chr [1:5] "10/10" "If this was.." "14 December 2018" "I have to say, and no..." ...
#  $ : chr [1:5] "10/10" "Stan Lee Is Smiling Right Now..." "17 December 2018" "A movie worthy of..." ...
#  $ : chr [1:6] "10/10" "the most visually stunning film I've ever seen..." "20 December 2018" "There's hardly anything... " ...
```

We *could* try to jump ahead (to the `do.call` below), but it will run into problems because our vectors have difference sizes. We can easily fix this by setting their lengths to the length of the longest vector. Here's a trick to do that:

```r
z <- lapply(y, `length<-`, max(lengths(y)))
str(z)
# List of 3
#  $ : chr [1:6] "10/10" "If this was.." "14 December 2018" "I have to say, and no..." ...
#  $ : chr [1:6] "10/10" "Stan Lee Is Smiling Right Now..." "17 December 2018" "A movie worthy of..." ...
#  $ : chr [1:6] "10/10" "the most visually stunning film I've ever seen..." "20 December 2018" "There's hardly anything... " ...
```

And the final step:

```r
setNames(do.call("rbind.data.frame", c(z, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)),
         letters[seq_len(length(z[[1]]))])
#       a                                                 b                c
# 1 10/10                                     If this was.. 14 December 2018
# 2 10/10                  Stan Lee Is Smiling Right Now... 17 December 2018
# 3 10/10 the most visually stunning film I've ever seen... 20 December 2018
#                             d     e    f
# 1    I have to say, and no... 10/10 <NA>
# 2        A movie worthy of... 10/10 <NA>
# 3 There's hardly anything...      .    .
```

Comment: why not `data.frame(matrix(trimws(x$col1),ncol = 6,byrow = T),stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: That works if the number of rows per block is always the same. In the data provided in the question, it is not. (I readily concede that the sample data is not likely to be "real" so is non-representative.)

Comment: OP said the pattern was repeating. I guess there might be more meaning to that